# Why is my register not updating in the testbench?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, test-bench

I have a register that I increment by a different value base on the different inputs, When I run a test bench to check it, the value does not increment. Not sure why. Attached is my code and the TB, as well as a screen shot of the simulation:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module TEMP_P1(
    input clk,
    input reset,

    input inquarter,
    input indime,
    input innickle,
    input inbev1,
    input inbev2,
    input inbev3,
    
    output reg [3:0] outquarter,
    output reg [3:0] outdime,
    output reg [3:0] outnickle,
    output reg [1:0] outbev1,
    output reg [1:0] outbev2,
    output reg [1:0] outbev3
    );
    
    reg [31:0] total;
    reg [3:0] quarter_count;
    reg [3:0] dime_count;
    reg [3:0] nickle_count;
    
    always@(clk)begin
        if(reset)begin
            total = 0;
            quarter_count = 0;
            dime_count = 0;
            nickle_count = 0;
        end else begin
            if (inquarter) begin
                quarter_count = quarter_count + 1;
                total = total + 25;
            end
            if (indime) begin
                dime_count = dime_count + 1;
                total = total + 10;
            end
            if (innickle) begin
                nickle_count = nickle_count + 1;
                total = total + 5;
            end
            
            if ((inbev1 === 1) && ( total >= 100)) begin
                outbev1 = 1;
                total = total - 100;
            end
            if ((inbev2 == 1) && ( total >= 120)) begin
                outbev2 = 1;
                total = total - 120;
            end
            if ((inbev3 == 1) && ( total >= 115)) begin
                outbev3 = 1;
                total = total - 115;
            end
            
            if (total >= 25) begin
                outquarter = 1;
                outdime = 0;
                outnickle = 0;
                total = total - 25;
            end 
            if ((total >= 10) && (total < 25)) begin
                outquarter = 0;
                outdime = 1;
                outnickle = 0;
                total = total - 10;
            end 
            if ((total >= 5) && (total < 10)) begin
                outquarter = 0;
                outdime = 0;
                outnickle = 1;
                total = total - 5;
            end 
        end
        
    end
endmodule
    

`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module TEMP_P1_TB(
    );
    
    reg clk;
    reg reset;

    reg inquarter;
    reg indime;
    reg innickle;
    reg inbev1;
    reg inbev2;
    reg inbev3;
    
    wire [3:0] outquarter;
    wire [3:0] outdime;
    wire [3:0] outnickle;
    wire [1:0] outbev1;
    wire [1:0] outbev2;
    wire [1:0] outbev3;
    
    TEMP_P1 UUT(.clk(clk), .reset(reset), .inquarter(inquarter), .indime(indime), .innickle(innickle), .inbev1(inbev1), .inbev2(inbev2), .inbev3(inbev3), 
                .outquarter(outquarter), .outdime(outdime), .outnickle(outnickle), .outbev1(outbev1), .outbev2(outbev2), .outbev3(outbev3));
    
    initial begin
        clk = 0;
        reset = 0;
        
        inquarter = 0;
        indime = 0;
        innickle = 0;
        inbev1 = 0;
        inbev2 = 0;
        inbev3 = 0;
        #10;
        
        reset = 1;
        #1
        reset = 0;
        #1
        
        inquarter = 1;
        #1;
        
        inquarter = 0;
        #1;
        
        inquarter = 1;
        #1;
        
        inquarter = 0;
        #1;
        
        inquarter = 1;
        #1;
        
        inquarter = 0;
        #1;
        
        inquarter = 1;
        #1;
        
        inquarter = 0;
        #1;
        
        inquarter = 1;
        #1;
        
        inquarter = 0;
        #1;
        
        inbev1 = 1;
        #1;
        
        inbev1 = 0;
        #1;
        
    end
    
    always begin
        #1 clk = ~clk;
    end
    
endmodule
```

[image]

I have tried changing blocking v. nonblocking assignments.

Answer (score 0):

In the UUT, add the keyword posedge to @ statement, like this:

```
  always@(posedge clk)begin
```

In the testbench, assert reset at the beginning, release it a couple of clocks later,  don't assert it again.  It was asserted for 1/2 of a clock some time after the test was started.  Best practice is to assert it at the unless there is a good reason not to do so.

```
initial begin
    reset = 1;
    #5 reset = 0;
```

Use non-blocking assignments everywhere in the UUT @ statement for the clocked process like this (I did not fix them all, you should).  Non-blocking assignments in a synchronous process is the correct way model registers:

```
  always@(posedge clk)begin
    if(reset)begin
        total <= 0;
        quarter_count <= 0;
        dime_count <= 0;
        nickle_count <= 0;
    end else begin
        if (inquarter) begin
            quarter_count <= quarter_count + 1;
            total <= total + 25;
```

In the testbench, hold the inputs (example inquarter) for at least 1 clock cycle so that they are able to be sampled at a logic 1, at the clock edge.  inquarter is 1/2 a clock cycle wide.    The clk period is #2, so if you change an input every #1, that is making a skinny pulse that would be easy for the DUT to miss.  I did not fix these in the testbench you should.  Register quarter_count is catching the input at 1 almost by accident in my simulation.

Make these changes and the registers start behaving as registers.

The waves looks like this for me on edaplayground:
[image]

Another issue is that you have an always block in the testbench

```
always begin
    #1 clk = ~clk;
```

however there is no $finish or $stop anywhere in your code.  The simulation will run forever until you click some sort of kill/stop in the simulation GUI, or kill the process from the command line.  The solution to this is to add a

```
$finish;
```

at the end of the testbench main initial block.   Now the simulation will compile, elaborate, run, and stop relatively quickly.   My eda playground simulation run of your post takes about 15 seconds total.

Answer (score 0):

One major problem with your code is that you have Verilog simulation race conditions.

To model registers, you need to use these coding styles:

- Signal changes triggered off only **one** edge of the clock (positive, for example):

  ```
   @(posedge clk)
  ```
- Nonblocking assignments: `<=`

This style must be used in both the **design** and **testbench**.

For the design, refer to [these simple code examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog#Example).

In the testbench, you should replace all of the `#` delays, except for the `clk` signal, with `@(posedge clk)`.  This assures that the inputs will be synchronous to the clock.  `clk` should use a blocking assignment; so there is no need to change your code there.

Also, the testbench code can be easier to understand if you use loops.  I use `repeat` loops.  Here are all the changes to both the design and testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module TEMP_P1(
    input clk,
    input reset,

    input inquarter,
    input indime,
    input innickle,
    input inbev1,
    input inbev2,
    input inbev3,

    output reg [3:0] outquarter,
    output reg [3:0] outdime,
    output reg [3:0] outnickle,
    output reg [1:0] outbev1,
    output reg [1:0] outbev2,
    output reg [1:0] outbev3
    );

    reg [31:0] total;
    reg [3:0] quarter_count;
    reg [3:0] dime_count;
    reg [3:0] nickle_count;

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset) begin
            total <= 0;
            quarter_count <= 0;
            dime_count <= 0;
            nickle_count <= 0;
        end else begin
            if (inquarter) begin
                quarter_count <= quarter_count + 1;
                total <= total + 25;
            end
            if (indime) begin
                dime_count <= dime_count + 1;
                total <= total + 10;
            end
            if (innickle) begin
                nickle_count <= nickle_count + 1;
                total <= total + 5;
            end

            if ((inbev1 === 1) && ( total >= 100)) begin
                outbev1 <= 1;
                total <= total - 100;
            end
            if ((inbev2 == 1) && ( total >= 120)) begin
                outbev2 <= 1;
                total <= total - 120;
            end
            if ((inbev3 == 1) && ( total >= 115)) begin
                outbev3 <= 1;
                total <= total - 115;
            end

            if (total >= 25) begin
                outquarter <= 1;
                outdime <= 0;
                outnickle <= 0;
                total <= total - 25;
            end
            if ((total >= 10) && (total < 25)) begin
                outquarter <= 0;
                outdime <= 1;
                outnickle <= 0;
                total <= total - 10;
            end
            if ((total >= 5) && (total < 10)) begin
                outquarter <= 0;
                outdime <= 0;
                outnickle <= 1;
                total <= total - 5;
            end
        end

    end
endmodule


`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module TEMP_P1_TB;
    reg clk;
    reg reset;

    reg inquarter;
    reg indime;
    reg innickle;
    reg inbev1;
    reg inbev2;
    reg inbev3;

    wire [3:0] outquarter;
    wire [3:0] outdime;
    wire [3:0] outnickle;
    wire [1:0] outbev1;
    wire [1:0] outbev2;
    wire [1:0] outbev3;

    TEMP_P1 UUT(.clk(clk), .reset(reset), .inquarter(inquarter), .indime(indime), .innickle(innickle), .inbev1(inbev1), .inbev2(inbev2), .inbev3(inbev3),
                .outquarter(outquarter), .outdime(outdime), .outnickle(outnickle), .outbev1(outbev1), .outbev2(outbev2), .outbev3(outbev3));

    initial begin
        clk <= 0;
        reset <= 0;

        inquarter <= 0;
        indime <= 0;
        innickle <= 0;
        inbev1 <= 0;
        inbev2 <= 0;
        inbev3 <= 0;

        repeat (5) @(posedge clk);
        reset <= 1;
        repeat (1) @(posedge clk);
        reset <= 0;

        repeat (5) begin
            repeat (1) @(posedge clk);
            inquarter <= 1;
            repeat (1) @(posedge clk);
            inquarter <= 0;
        end

        repeat (1) @(posedge clk);
        inbev1 <= 1;
        repeat (1) @(posedge clk);
        inbev1 <= 0;

        repeat (10) @(posedge clk);
        $finish;
    end

    always begin
        #1 clk = ~clk;
    end
endmodule
```

The above code fixes the timing problems (race conditions).

However, you also have problems with your logic since the `total` gets cleared after each quarter input, as you can see in the waves below:

[image: waves]

If that is not your intended behavior, I recommend you spend more time looking at your internal waveforms.  If you still have problems, you can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).